# Docker-in-Docker with Alpine 3.8

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, docker-in-docker

Recently the DIND release was updated from using Alpine 3.8 to Alpine 3.9.
Alpine 3.9 supports only Node 10.14. This is problematic because Node 10.14 is incompatible with several required packages, such as ursa and @newrelic/nativemetrics... these work well with Alpine 3.8, which supports Node 8.14.

We've been using DIND as our build's pipline Jenkins agent in a Docker Swarm.
With the above upgrade, DIND with Alpine 3.8 is no longer available and we're now in a situation where our build pipeline is broken...

Can someone suggest a way to get DIND with Alpine 3.8?
This is the Dockerfile: https://github.com/IdanAdar/test-docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stick with an older image like `docker:18.06.2-dind`. Alternatively take the upstream [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/master/18.09/Dockerfile) and edit the alpine version to your liking. No guaranty the build will still work, but could be worth a try.

In the long run you probably want your dependencies to be upgraded to versions compatible with more recent Node releases.

Comment: Yes, if we manage to get the `ursa` package maintainer to fix the incompatibility with Node 10 we will definitely upgrade. Right now it's out of our hands...

Comment: I did try to clone the docker dind repo and update the Dockerfile in the 18.6 folder to alpine:3.8, but this still used Node 10 for some reason.

Comment: Thus far this seems promising: https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/144#issuecomment-468461904